# How can I update the database with values from the dataset?

Tags: c#, database, dataset

```
string s = "Select number,name from table where id = 5 and num = 20";

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(s, con);
adapter.Fill(dset, "ABC");

SqlCommandBuilder sT = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.Update(ds,"ABC");
```

The following code throws an exception, saying that the table `ABC` cannot be found

Comment: Good formatting is your friend. Use it.

Comment: Your update uses a different dataset from the select...

Comment: @Paddy Hah, that's a good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as Paddy [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277555/how-can-i-update-the-database-with-values-from-the-dataset#comment41227380_26277555), your `.Fill` and `.Update` methods uses different `DataSet`'s. One is `dset` and the other one is `ds`.

I think this exception occurs on `adapter.Update(ds,"ABC");` line because [`DbDataAdapter.Fill` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4b211hz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) creates `ABC` table in your `dset` even if doesn't have table named `ABC`.

> The Fill method supports scenarios where the DataSet contains multiple
>   DataTable objects whose names differ only by case. In such situations,
>   Fill performs a case-sensitive comparison to find the corresponding
>   table, **and creates a new table if no exact match exists**.

But [`DbDataAdapter.Update` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19c81fk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't do that. It doesn't create a new table in your `DataSet` if you try to update a table which doesn't exist.

Closest thing this `.Update` method search for a case-sensitive match (which is `abc` in this case) and if it can't find it, throws exception.